# EXCEL - Populate a column based on a mixture of Y , N in 4 other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a calculation whereby I have a table of 8 columns. column 1 asks `Y/N` and column 2 populates a cost based on the answer of column 1. Then same process is repeated in columns: `3 and 4`, `5 and 6`, `7 and 8`.

What I'm after, if possible, is based on the mixture condition of `Y/N` and the corresponding text for each combination. The text is a stock code based on the features (`Y/N`) selected.

So for example:

```
Y, N, N, N --> TEXT1

Y, Y, N, N --> TEXT2

Y, N, Y, N --> TEXT3

N, Y, Y, N --> TEXT4
```

*Original [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jff5g.png)*

Comment: Put the question in the question and not a picture.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Nested `If()` statements perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the Y/N results to one string and lookt it up via match in your list/database.

This would be the formula you need:

```
=INDEX($T$6:$T$18,MATCH(A1&C1&E1&G1,$S$6:$S$18,0))
```

[image: index formula]